# How can I make PhpStorm warn me about deprecated HTML features?

Tags: html, phpstorm, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I would like PhpStorm to warn me about deprecated features in my HTML code. At first, I thought this was somehow not working correctly when writing HTML code in PHP files, but now I tried it with an HTML-only file and there are still no warnings.

For reference, this is my test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="123" frame="no"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Both the `width` and `frame` attributes on the `<table>` tag are deprecated. However, PhpStorm inspections tell me "No problems found".

How can I enable warnings for deprecated HTML features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works .. but not for HTML5 as it has no schema in `<doctype>` tag.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16881 - -watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.